# SUM, JOIN, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, PARTITION, OVER. What am I missing?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, sum

I need a bit of help. I have two tables that I know needs to be joined, not a problem. What I need to display is the invoice number, invoice date and the total dollar amount for all products purchased in the invoice. The info needs to be ordered by invoice number in descending order and then by invoice date in ascending order. What I have so far, and is throwing errors, is:

```
SELECT          LINE.INV_NUMBER, 
                INVOICE.INV_DATE, 
                SUM(LINE.LINE_PRICE) 
           FROM LINE 
FULL OUTER JOIN INVOICE ON LINE.INV_NUMBER=INVOICE.INV_NUMBER 
       GROUP BY LINE.INV_NUMBER 
       ORDER BY LINE.INV_NUMBER DESC, 
                INVOICE.INV_DATE ASC;
```

Any help is appreciated before I pull all my hair out.

Update:

I have updated my statement to :

```
SELECT LINE.INV_NUMBER AS "Line Number", 
       INVOICE.INV_DATE AS "Invoice Date", 
       SUM(LINE.LINE_PRICE) AS "Total Sales" 
  FROM INVOICE FULL OUTER JOIN LINE ON INVOICE.INV_NUMBER=LINE.INV_NUMBER 
 GROUP BY LINE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE
 ORDER BY LINE.INV_NUMBER DESC, INVOICE.INV_DATE ASC;
```

and I am getting data instead of errors. What I am now having a problem with is I need the data to read Ordered by the Invoice Number in a descending order and by Invoice Date in ascending order, so I am assuming that I need two data outputs. How would I do that?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I was getting*Cause:        

Error starting at line 26 in command:
SELECT LINE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE, SUM(LINE.LINE_PRICE) FROM LINE LEFT JOIN INVOICE ON LINE.INV_NUMBER=INVOICE.INV_NUMBER GROUP BY LINE.INV_NUMBE ORDER BY LINE.INV_NUMBER DESC, INVOICE.INV_DATE ASC
Error at Command Line:26 Column:139
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "LINE"."INV_NUMBE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:    
    
But I have changed my code by putting INVOICE.INV_DATE in the Group By and am getting data.

Comment: What I am now having a problem with is I need the data to read Ordered by the Invoice Number in a descending order and by Invoice Date in ascending order, so i am assuming that I need two data outputs. How would I do that?

Comment: Why can't you just run two queries?

Comment: It is the last question to an assignment that I am already late with and it states that it has to be done in one query,

Comment: Your order by clause should be working, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Line Number Invoice Date Total Sales
----------- ------------ -----------
       1008 17-JAN-12         135.77 
       1007 17-JAN-12          19.98 
       1006 17-JAN-12         383.85 
       1005 17-JAN-12           5.87 
       1004 17-JAN-12          14.94 
       1003 16-JAN-12          93.89 
       1002 16-JAN-12           4.99 
       1001 16-JAN-12          24.94 

 8 rows selected  
 
The above is my output. One ORDER BY is DESC while the other is ASC. Looking at my data, they are shown as both descending. How do I fix it to where it is ordered correctly.

Comment: Invoice dates are in descending order because earlier invoices have smaller invoice numbers. So ordering by date after invoice number has no effect assuming invoice numbers are unique. Ordering by date in your query is only used for rows where invoice numbers are the same. The only way you can have is with UNION ALL. So make two queries: one where you order by invoice number and in the other order by date and add union all between them. This way you get two lists in the same result set.

Answer (score 0):

Only those columns which are used in group by can be retrieved in the select clause I believe.

May be you need to include INV_DATE, LINE_PRICE and then retrieve their aggregate's in the select clause.

refer to few group by examples in java2s.com that is a useful site.

Regards,
Srihari

Comment: I did what you had suggested before I saw your post and I am actually getting data instead of errors. What I am now having a problem with is I need the data to read Ordered by the Invoice Number in a descending order and by Invoice Date in ascending order, so i am assuming that I need two data outputs. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `GROUP BY LINE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE`

Depending on the DBMS you're using, it may or may not be the issue.

Comment: I did what you had suggested before I saw your post and I am actually getting data instead of errors. What I am now having a problem with is I need the data to read Ordered by the Invoice Number in a descending order and by Invoice Date in ascending order, so i am assuming that I need two data outputs. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LINE.INV_NUMBER AS "Line Number", 
       INVOICE.INV_DATE AS "Invoice Date", 
       SUM(LINE.LINE_PRICE) AS "Total Sales" 
  FROM INVOICE FULL OUTER JOIN LINE ON INVOICE.INV_NUMBER=LINE.INV_NUMBER 
 GROUP BY LINE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE
 ORDER BY INVOICE.INV_DATE ASC, LINE.INV_NUMBER DESC;
```